# Symfony show picture extension

Tags: php, symfony

I have one application with a class user and document, every user have a picture profile (document) it works fine.
But now I'm having problems, for example on the header of the page I show the picture:

```
{% if app.user.picture %}
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/' ~ app.user.picture.Id) }}" alt="" class="img-circle">
{% else %}
<img src="{{ asset('images/default.png') }}" alt="" class="img-circle">
{% endif %}
```

and I got the html code:

```
<img src="/Project/web/uploads/30" alt="" class="img-circle">
```

this code works perfect on my localhost, but now I uploaded this to the server and the picture is not showing.
But if I add the extension on the browser It show me exactly what I want.
Here is my Document entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;
    private $temp;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($n) {
        $this->name = $n;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($d) {
        $this->createdAt = $d;
    }

    public function setPath() {
        $this->path = $this->id;
    }

    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null) {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile() {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->id . '.' . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath() {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir() {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload() {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload() {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }
        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does

        $this->getFile()->move(
                $this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->id . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );
        $this->setFile(null);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function storeFilenameForRemove() {
        $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload() {
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            unlink($this->temp);
        }
    }

}
```

And my Document.orm.yml:

```
...\Entity\Document:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: ...\Entity\DocumentRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        path:
            type: string
            length: '255'
            nullable: true
        file:
            type: string
            length: '255'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

In my account controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('...Bundle:User')->find($this->getUser()->getId());

        $originalpic = $entity->getPicture();
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('form_user');

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {

            if ($editForm->get('password')->getData()) {
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
                $entity->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($editForm->get('password')->getData(), $entity->getSalt()));
            }

            if ($uploadedFile['picture']) {
                foreach ($uploadedFile as $file) {
                    $pic = new Document();
                    $pic->setName($entity->getUsername());
                    $pic->setFile($file);
                    $pic->setPath();
                    $entity->setPicture($pic);
                    $em->persist($pic);
                    $em->flush();
                    $pic->upload();
                }
            } else {
                $entity->setPicture($originalpic);
            }


            $em->flush();

            $this->container->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Information updated');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_profile'));
        }

        return $this->render('...Bundle:Panel\Pages\Account:edit.html.twig', array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView()
        ));
    }
```

My question is, how can I change my code to show me the picture with the extension
/////
The solution was add another raw to the table and in Document Entity:

```
public function upload() {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }
        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does

        $this->extension = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        $this->getFile()->move(
                $this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->id . '.' . $this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $extension;


//get image extension
  public function getImgExtension(){
    return $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalExtension();

}
 /**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $extension
 * @return Document
 */
public function setExtension($extension)
{
    $this->extension = $extension;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getExtension()
{
    return $this->extension;
}
```

to get image extension, add this property and method in your Document Entity.
Then run this command from your terminal:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and in your twig file just include:

```
<img src="{{asset(document.WebPath)}}.{{document.extension}}" alt="" class="img-circle">
```

Comment: I added to Document entity: /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $extension;
    public function getExtension() {
        return $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalExtension();
    }
but I got Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object
when I try to do: {{app.user.picture.extension}}

Comment: I didnt create a controller for this, is the base.html.twig, I'm doing this: {{app.user.picture.extension}}

Comment: you did not upload your picture ??

Comment: yes I got the pictures on the server, there's no problem with this, I edited my post with the Account controller, editaction

Comment: fixed, thank you for the help, it was almost your solution, post edited with solution